# Do all servers have one base OS, like in RED HAT openstack architecture?

Tags: networking, redhat, cloud, openstack

I'm a noob learning openstack. And The resources are all over the place tbh. I came across this image and would like to know one thing,
[image]
So, Suppose I have 100TB of storage and 10 server grade processors, and ram of 1TB, do all these resources make up of only one base OS- RED hat enterprise Linux? So, they sell resources to connect all the equipment and connect to install one single OS which can comprehend them all?
And Upon this, we throw an Openstack architecture so clients can use them as needed? Do we need as many NICs or the NICs virtual?

on the NICs, I mean- by definition(at consumer scale-like one laptop) we need a network interface card for one IP. And to act as an interface. So, in the case of cloud, are the IP addresses all mapped to real physical NICs or Openstack uses one big special NIC which has one public IP and all IPs hop through it?

Also here is the original question please read the comments, I couldn't actually migrate due to my experience points.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65862267/do-all-servers-have-one-base-os-like-in-red-hat-openstack-architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenStack is a collection of software projects that create useful infrastructure out of raw compute resources. Typically you could create a few hundred small VMs out of what you have. Compare to your favorite public cloud: self service standard APIs, and the consumer does not have to concern themselves with hardware.

One giant OS instance running on many nodes is a bit different. That is a thing in the high performance computing area. Think TOP500 list. I don't think HPC is a common use case of OpenStack, HPC already has specialized tooling.

Red Hat has their own OpenStack distribution, packaging up these components and helping deploy them. (Help probably is required, I have heard the learning curve is steep.) Of course Red Hat has their own Linux distribution as a target platform to run everything on. RHEL at the bottom there is a logical, rather than physical relationship, as the "foundation" to build things on. There actually are many nodes where these services run. A dozen tiny RHEL logos would be difficult to read, so it just spans the diagram.

I am not qualified to say much about [OpenStack Neutron networking](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/latest/admin/intro-os-networking.html). Neutron provides network services, in a broad, generic, and object focused way. Layer 2 and 3 connectivity, overlay encapsulation, firewall as a service, IPAM and DNS services, hardware offload. All components you may want in a modern multi tenant compute service. More fundamental than how to address a vNIC, how do you want to design your network?